# python socket, getting unwanted output (newbie)

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to learn socket programming using python, but kept getting unwanted output i.e. i'm expecting "BIG" instead of "b'BIG'".
Where have I went wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

-w.e.

---

At client (tcpclient.py) :
Output :-

```
C:>python tcpclient.py
Lowercase:big
Reply from Server:  b'BIG'
C:>
```

My coding as below :

At client (tcpclient.py) :

```
    from socket import *
    serverName = '127.0.0.1'
    serverPort = 12000
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
    sentence = input("Lowercase sentence:")
    clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
    modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    print ("Reply from Server: ",modifiedSentence)
    clientSocket.close()
```

At server (tcpserver.py)

```
    from socket import *
    serverPort = 12000
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(1)
    print("The server is ready to receive")
    while 1:
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
        connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
```